# OpenGL: Set several texture coordinates

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

How to set several texture coordinates for one vertex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Immediate Mode you use `glMultiTexCoord` for this: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultiTexCoord.xml

Code example

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE0, s0, t0);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE1, s1, t1);
glMultiTexCoord2f(GL_TEXTURE2, s2, t2);
glVertex3f(...);

/* ... */
glEnd();
```

Using Vertex Arrays you use `glClientActiveTexture` to select the texture unit the following calls to `glTexCoordPointer` are related to.

If you're using shaders you may as well assign multiple texture coordinates to a set of vertex attributes.